# recursive - check if array is increasing

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, recursion, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm attempting to create a method that checks an array for increasing elements recursively. `True` should be returned if all the elements are in increasing order. I get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` when I compare `arr[i+1]`. Any ideas on how I can make it work.

```
public static boolean isAscending(int[] array) {
    int n = array.length - 1;
    if(array.length == 0 || array.length == 1 || n == 1) 
        return true;
    else if (array[n] <= array[n-1]){  
        return false;
    }

    if isAscending(array);
        return true;
}
```

Comment: `if isAscending(array);` will not compile. Is some of the code missing ?

Comment: @MAV: Been awhile since I've done straight Java, but why not just return the result of your recursive call?

Comment: Every time you call this, it will do exactly the same thing.

Comment: You have a ; right behind your if statement. That is for sure not right. Your method will never end if array [n]> array [n-1] and n more than 1.

Comment: @ChristopherPoile It is not _my_ recursive call. ;) The reason I am asking OP if some of the code is missing is because (s)he got a runtime exception (and mentions `arr[i+1]` which is not present in the code), so there must be a mismatch between OPs local code and the code posted.

Comment: @MAV also this won't compile since not all paths lead to a `return` so `return isAscending(...)` is probably better.

Answer (score 0):

Besides I don't see any `arr[i+1]`, you have to decrease the size of the array you're calling recursively with (and remove the `;` after the last `if`), otherwise you'll call the method with the same input over and over again.

Comment: I hope you aren't suggesting creating and copying to a new array before making the next recursive call. That is `O(n^2)` and is more complex than just keeping track of the current index to compare.

Comment: Are we *really* talking about complexity when writing an iterative task as a recursive function? :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep track of which index you are currently looking at. Right now you are always looking at the last index in the array. Also, you currently don't check if the first two indexes are in ascending order, as you currently stop when `n == 1` not `n == 0`.

```
public static boolean isAscending( int[] array ){ return isAscendingHelper( array, array.length - 1 ); }

private static boolean isAscendingHelper( int[] array, int index )
{
    if( index <= 0 )
       return true;
    else if( array[index] <= array[index-1] )
       return false;
    else
       return isAscendingHelper( array, index - 1 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to maintain your original method signature:

```
public static boolean isAscending(int[] array) {
  if (array.length == 0 || array.length == 1) {
    return true;
  }
  int[] temp = Arrays.copyOfRange(array, 1, array.length);
  if (array[0] < temp[0]) {
    return isAscending(temp);
  }
  return false;
}
```